# SharePoint Designer 2010 workflows stuck on in progress

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type, designer-workflow

I was following this blog http://sharepointgypsy.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/create-state-machine-workflow-with.html about SharePoint Designer 2010 state machine workflows and edited the choices in the site column Task Status list from the defaults to 'approved' and 'rejected'. I probably should have done this just on the custom content type.

I now find that other workflows on the same site aren't completing, e.g. a 'collect data from a user' action remains 'in progress' after the task has been completed. I suspect this is something to do with editing the default choices. I've tried putting the Task Status site column back to the normal choices; Not Started,In Progress...etc.

I only have access to the site in SharePoint Designer, so I have to try and fix it from here. Any ideas how to get back to normal?

Comment: This is happening to me too.  I'm totally dead in the water with this problem.  I did modify the Task Status values as well, but like you I changed them BACK.